# Building vectors/calculating dot products in r

Tags: r, excel, csv, vector

Edit: I have edited the code many times yet still get this error in return Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 75

I am building vectors in R from an excel sheet of data, then trying to create a new file with the angle between these vectors. I am a little confused by the last few lines of code where the calculation of the angle between the two vectors gets plugged into a new file (original .csv is in wd used to get the MonardaME and sulfur vector data).

```
> d<- read.csv(file.choose(), header=T,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> attach(d)
> MonardaME
 [1]  0.000  0.000 41.500  0.000  0.000  0.000 21.685  0.000  0.000 21.535
[11]  0.565  0.000 38.515  9.055  0.000  0.000 20.300 47.020  0.000  0.000
[21]  0.000  0.000  1.945  0.000  0.690  0.000 75.740  0.000  0.000  0.565
[31]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
[41]  8.530 79.275  1.945  0.000  0.205  0.000  9.210  0.270  0.000  0.000
[51]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
[61]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000 79.275  9.095  0.000  0.000  0.000
[71]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
> sulfur
 [1]  0.000  0.000 89.220  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
[11]  0.000  0.000 49.815  4.995  0.000  0.000 38.055  0.000  0.000  0.000
[21]  0.000 44.820  5.070  0.000  0.000  0.000 35.465  0.000  5.070  0.000
[31]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  7.920
[41] 35.465  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  3.940  0.000  0.000  0.000
[51]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
[61]  0.000  0.000  3.120  0.000  2.590 80.285  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
[71]  0.000  4.995  0.000  0.000
> as.numeric(sulfur)
 [1]  0.000  0.000 89.220  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
[11]  0.000  0.000 49.815  4.995  0.000  0.000 38.055  0.000  0.000  0.000
[21]  0.000 44.820  5.070  0.000  0.000  0.000 35.465  0.000  5.070  0.000
[31]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  7.920
[41] 35.465  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  3.940  0.000  0.000  0.000
[51]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
[61]  0.000  0.000  3.120  0.000  2.590 80.285  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
[71]  0.000  4.995  0.000  0.000
> as.numeric(MonardaME)
 [1]  0.000  0.000 41.500  0.000  0.000  0.000 21.685  0.000  0.000 21.535
[11]  0.565  0.000 38.515  9.055  0.000  0.000 20.300 47.020  0.000  0.000
[21]  0.000  0.000  1.945  0.000  0.690  0.000 75.740  0.000  0.000  0.565
[31]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
[41]  8.530 79.275  1.945  0.000  0.205  0.000  9.210  0.270  0.000  0.000
[51]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
[61]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000 79.275  9.095  0.000  0.000  0.000
[71]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
> focalScent<-readline(prompt="MonardaME")
MonardaME
> focalScentName=focalScent
> samples=colnames(d)
> a=match('dimensions', samples)
> samples=samples[-a]
> a=match(focalScent, samples)
> samples=samples[-a]
> d2<-d[,-1]
> rownames(d2)<-d[,-1]
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  invalid 'row.names' length
> rownames(d2)<-d[,1]
> attach(d2)
The following objects are masked from d:

    MonardaME, MonardaMErun1, MonardaMErun2, sulfur, sulfurRun1,
    sulfurRun2
> angleData=c(0,0)
> anglefileName<-"MonardaSulfur"
> anglefileName<-"MonardaSulfur"
> MonardaSulfur
Error: object 'MonardaSulfur' not found
> "MonardaSulfur"
[1] "MonardaSulfur"
> anglefileName<-"MonardaSulfurAngle"
> MonardaSulfurAngle
Error: object 'MonardaSulfurAngle' not found
> "MonardaSulfurAngle"
[1] "MonardaSulfurAngle"
> anglefileName
[1] "MonardaSulfurAngle"
> write.table(angleData,file=anglefileName,append=FALSE,row.names = FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
> assign("vec1", c(MonardaME))
> vec1
 [1]  0.000  0.000 41.500  0.000  0.000  0.000 21.685  0.000  0.000 21.535
[11]  0.565  0.000 38.515  9.055  0.000  0.000 20.300 47.020  0.000  0.000
[21]  0.000  0.000  1.945  0.000  0.690  0.000 75.740  0.000  0.000  0.565
[31]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
[41]  8.530 79.275  1.945  0.000  0.205  0.000  9.210  0.270  0.000  0.000
[51]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
[61]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000 79.275  9.095  0.000  0.000  0.000
[71]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
> assign("vec2", c(sulfur))
> vec2
 [1]  0.000  0.000 89.220  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
[11]  0.000  0.000 49.815  4.995  0.000  0.000 38.055  0.000  0.000  0.000
[21]  0.000 44.820  5.070  0.000  0.000  0.000 35.465  0.000  5.070  0.000
[31]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  7.920
[41] 35.465  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  3.940  0.000  0.000  0.000
[51]  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
[61]  0.000  0.000  3.120  0.000  2.590 80.285  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
[71]  0.000  4.995  0.000  0.000
> vec1=MonardaME
> for(i in samples){}
> for(i in samples){
+ a=vec1*vec1
+ vectorLength1=sqrt(sum(a))
+ b=vec2*vec2
+ vectorLength2=sqrt(sum(b))
+ dotVectors=vec1%*%vec2
+ Theta=acos(dotVectors/(vectorLength1*vectorLength2))
+ angleName= paste(MonardaME, i, sep="")
+ angleData<-c(angleName, Theta)
+ temporary<-read.table(anglefileName, header=FALSE, sep="")
+ temporary2<-cbind.data.frame(temporary,angleData)
+ write.table(temporary2,file=anglefileName,append=FALSE,sep=",")
+ }
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 75
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code produces an `Error` and a `Warning`. The `Error` is what breaks your code, the `Warning` is an issue you are made aware of, but it is not breaking your code.

The error message `no lines available in input` means that the file you are trying to read exists, but it is empty. Fixing this will make your code run.

The warning message `file("") only supports open = "w+" and open = "w+b": using the former` comes from the `write.table()` call and the `append` argument being set to `FALSE`. Changing this should make the warning go away, but won't make any difference to the results of your code.

It's a bit hard for me to figure out exactly what is going on, since I don't have your original csv file available. It seems though that the line `anglefileName<-readline(prompt = "MonardaSulfurAngle")` could be the reason for the error messages you get at the end. Try `anglefileName <- "MonardaSulfurAngle"` instead.

Also be aware that you have a few other error messages earlier. One of them is due to a typo (`samplse` should be `samples`).

Comment: thank you so much! the original .csv file contains the data I make my vectors with, but not sure why the new file I am trying to create with the angle data is empty, in fact it is not even showing up in my working drive...

Comment: That is because the name you are giving it is an empty string. Type `anglefileName` into the console it'll return `""`.